# Vectorization of a nested for-loop that inputs all paired combinations

Tags: r, vectorization, nested-loops

I thought that the following problem must have been answered or a function must exist to do it, but I was unable to find an answer.
I have a nested loop that takes a row from one 3-col. data frame and copies it next to each of the other rows, to form a 6-col. data frame (with all possible combinations). This works fine, but with a medium sized data set (800 rows), the loops take forever to complete the task.
I will demonstrate on a sample data set:

```
Sdat <- data.frame(
x = c(10,20,30,40),
y = c(15,25,35,45),
ID =c(1,2,3,4)
)

compar <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=6)) # to contain all combinations

names(compar) <- c("x","y", "ID", "x","y", "ID") 
N <- nrow(Sdat)     # how many different points we have

for (i in 1:N)
{
  for (j in 1:N)   
  {  
   Temp1 <-  Sdat[i,] # data from 1st point
   Temp2 <-  Sdat[j,]  # data from 2nd point
   C <- cbind(Temp1, Temp2)        
   compar <-   rbind(C,compar)
  }
}
```

These loops provide exactly the output that I need for further analysis. Any suggestion for vectorizing this section?

Comment: `expand.grid` , you may try this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ind <- seq_len(nrow(Sdat))
grid <- expand.grid(ind, ind)
compar <- cbind(Sdat[grid[, 1], ], Sdat[grid[, 2], ])
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution using rep (assuming you are happy with a data frame output):

```
compar <- data.frame(x = rep(Sdat$x, each = N),
                     y = rep(Sdat$y, each = N),
                     id = rep(1:n, each = N),
                     x1 = rep(Sdat$x, N),
                     y1 = rep(Sdat$y, N),
                     id_1 = rep(1:n, N))
```